# Writing the results of a search from a for loop to a file only give one line (one result)

Tags: python

I'm not understanding why I'm only getting the first match of word and ln in a logfile that I'm writing to in a loop (there are 50 or more matches). And and it's not well structured like when I print to the screen. Below is the code. Thanks!

Results in file that I'm writing: 343438363939
70642

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?:3\d){6}')
for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
            f = open(os.path.join(root,file))
                for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                    searchedstr = regex.findall(line)
                    ln = str(i)
                    for word in searchedstr:
                         print "\nString found: " + word
                         print "Line: " + ln
                         print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                         print " "
                         logfile = open('result3.log', 'w')
                         logfile.write(word + '\n' + ln)
                         logfile.close()
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
                 logfile = open('result3.log', 'w')
                 logfile.write(word + '\n' + ln)
                 logfile.close()
```

Every time you open the log file like this, it erases everything that was in it before and
starts writing from the *beginning* of the file.  You can either change the `open` to

```
                 logfile = open('result3.log', 'a')
```

('a' stands for 'append'), or -- better -- open `logfile` just once, outside the outermost loop, like so:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?:3\d){6}')
with open('result3.log', 'w') as logfile:
    for root, dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
        # ...
        logfile.write(word + '\n' + ln)
```

The `with` takes care of closing the file for you, so you don't need an explicit `logfile.close()`.  (It would be better style to use a `with` to open `f` as well, if only so the `f.close()` isn't dangling there below the nested loops.)  (Further addendum: `enumerate(f.readlines())` is the same as `enumerate(f)` except slower.)

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned and it worked, but was not readable. So, I tried: logfile.write('\nString:' + word + '\nLine:' + ln + '\n'). It works but, the loop of reading files seems never to stop. And when I try to delete the file that was created, It says the file is still open, when in fact, it's not. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would need to see the complete program.  Please start a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting your output file everytime you're writing to it because you open it with `'w'` instead of `'a'` for appending.

Maybe you should open it once outside of the loop.